# Uncaught FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I'm creating a e-commerce with Vue & Firebase. Trying to add some cart information from the current logged in user. Strange thing is at the very first time information saved perfectly. When I trying to add some again. That dosent work and show this error.

> Uncaught FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined

So I have to refresh that page. Then it work again. I cant understand where is the problem.

Note: If I try to add any other value instead of cart. then it works fine.

```
checkoutLoggedInUser(){
  var db = firebase.firestore();           
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

  db.collection("orders").add({
     user_id:user.uid,
     cart:this.$store.getters.cart                    
  })

  this.$store.commit('emptyCart')                
  this.$router.push({ name: 'Home'})
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That error message is saying that one of the fields you're trying to write to a document is `undefined` in JavaScript.  Check the values that you're passing by using console.log or using a debugger to figure out which one is undefined, then change your code to pass something else, or omit the field entirely.

Also bear in mind that the error message is referencing a call to `DocumentReference.set()`, but the code you're showing is calling `DocumentReference.add()`, so the error might be in a different location.

Comment: Please check my code. If I remove this "cart:this.$store.getters.cart". Then everything works fine. This error is only comes when I add Cart.

Comment: DId you check the values for `undefined`? That's what the error message is telling you is wrong.

Comment: Please check the screenshot  https://prnt.sc/olocds. This is the value uploaded perfectly at the first time. But when I try to add another value again. That dosent work. I have to refresh the page for add another value.

Comment: That screenshot doesn't show the entire object.  Is some nested value inside it undefined? No values may be undefined for addition to Firestore.

Comment: That's still not the whole thing.  When you see "..." and more disclosure arrows, there are more properties.

Comment: But when I refresh the page this things appear https://prnt.sc/olomgm.  and this time upload perfectly. Do you have any idea about what is this "loglevel:webpack-dev-server"

Comment: Sometimes one field may be *undefined*.